# How I can modularize static HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, gulp, erb

I'm a front-end developer. When I write a `html` code I repeat my self a lot by **copy and paste** (header section, footer section, etc).

How I can write modularize my `html` files? Like separate `header.html` and `footer.html`, and after that call both in `index.html`... same as `erb` in `Ruby on rails`? (I don't like `jade` lang)

Comment: Well you can use ajax for that, but it will require a http server for ajax calls. So you can install a simple http server.

Comment: @st. i use gulp, and i want tools for compile file to standard html file. like jade.

Comment: I know you said front-end development. But your problem is best resolved with server-side languages such as PHP (eg. Include and Require functions) which will allow for you to re-use different elements (header, footer, menu...) dynamically in an html document (generated by PHP).

Answer (score 9):

In PHP we would do something like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include 'inc/head.inc.php'; //DOCTYPE and <head> stuff
    include 'inc/header.inc.php'; //NAV or other top-of-page boilerplate
?>

<div id="uniqueDIV">
    //Your unique page-specific divs can go here
</div>

<?php include 'inc/footer.inc.php'; ?>
```

So, in your `head.inc.php` file, you just have the usual DOCTYPE and `<head>` portion of your page file.

In Ruby, it appears the equivalent instruction is something like:

```
load "inc/head_inc.rb"  -- OR --
require_relative "inc/head_inc.rb"
```

https://practicingruby.com/articles/ways-to-load-code

---

Another option is to use a bit of js/jQuery to populate parts of the document. If you don't have PHP, this is 2nd best option. *It's less optimal than PHP because the js/jQ code will run after the page is fully rendered, which may cause a minuscule (but noticeable) lag before the code appears.*

For example:

**html**

```
<div id="navbarDIV"></div>
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#navbarDIV').load( 'inc/navbar.inc.html' );
    });
</script>
```

Note that you will need jQuery loaded to use the above code. Simple as this line in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2dvuLuaj/)</kbd>

---

Final note: the script tag can be included in your `<head>` as an external file, or it can be plopped anywhere in your document with the rest of the html. Whatever works. But `<head>` as external file, or last element in body (also as an external file) are preferred.

Final final note: the ".inc." naming convention is not required, it's just my own practice. Include file could be named `head.html` or `head.php` or etc.

Comment: I agree 100% with using PHP includes - modular headers, footers etc. is _exactly_ what they are meant to be used for.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails], so I don't think he is also using PHP.  Your jQuery answer is fine though.

Comment: the only working solution for static HTML pages, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using something like [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/), which doesn't require a server (you can compile your templates locally).

Swig's syntax is much like Mustache or Handlebars, it uses braces and works inside of normal HTML, so you can retain the HTML syntax you want (unlike Jade).

For separating HTML into files to be reused, you can check out [Template Inheritance](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#inheritance).  You can also see [File Inclusion](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#include) and [File Imports](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#import).

Here is a small example:

```html
{% include "./header.html" %}

<div id="body">Hello world</div>

{% include "./footer.html" %}
```

---

> i use gulp, and i want tools for compile file to standard html file. like jade. – Sajad Abedi

For this you can use [gulp-swig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-swig) and build your templates locally in a task.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs), which is convenient.
You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

For `HTML` files there is no standard way for reusing `HTML` parts. You have to use into a templating system.

But **`erb`** is a templating system and can handle that. See this Stack Overflow answer about "[Including one erb file into another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10241263/146513)".