# Rendering nested ERB templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm building a templating system in Rails and I'm trying to get ERB to render the partial of a partial. Here's what I have so far -

*script.rb*

```
file = File.read(Rails.root + "app/views/example/_parent.html.erb")
ERB.new(file).result
```

*_parent.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'example/child', name: 'Jim' %>
```

*_child.html.erb*

```
<p>hello <%= name %></p>
```

---

When I run my script I get this error -

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for main:Object from (erb):1:in `<main>'
```

I want it to return -

```
<p>hello Jim</p>
```

I'm pretty new to the working with ERB under the hood so it might be something easy I'm missing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236049/including-one-erb-file-into-another

Comment: I just stumbled upon that actually, I should've posted it. Thanks.