# How do I get document.getElementsByTagName('').innerHTML to make text between 2 tags?

Tags: javascript, html, include

I'm trying to use JavaScript to include a footer on several webpages, so if I want to change the footer, I only have to change it in one place. PHP is not available on this server and neither are server side inserts (SSI), but Perl, Python, and Tcl are available. I have been trying with `document.getElementsByTagName('footer').innerHTML = "text";` but it doesn't produce text. I copied this code from dev.mozilla, and it tells me how many tags I have:

```
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
var num = footer.length;
console.log('There is ' + num + ' footer in this document');
```

So, I don't know what's wrong with the innerHTML script. I also tried with paragraph tags and got the same results in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that getElementsByTagName() results in an array, so I have to refer to the footer's index with [0]:

```
var footerTags = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
footerTags[0].innerHTML = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

I reccoment using textContent instead. Se why [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

To see how it works, paste the following into your browser console while you're on StackOverflow and hit *enter*.

```
document.querySelector('.site-footer').textContent = 'Custom footer content.'
```

note: use `querySelector` with a **class** instead of `getElementByTagName`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Before asking this question, I had searched for Python includes without any luck, so I stopped there, but after asking this question, I thought that I should search for Perl/Ruby includes. Today, I found out that [I can use the Perl use function](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-include-a-file-in-perl/2152/3), so I could [study that](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/use.html) and try to implement it although I am completely new to Perl. [Ruby also appears capable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10241263/2654885), perhaps even more. I have no experience with Ruby either, but maybe I should start there.